# Justifying the closure under addition of $\ell^1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, solution-verification

$
\newcommand{\setb}[2]{\left \{ #1 \; \middle| \; #2 \right \} }
\newcommand{\seq}[1]{ \left\{ #1 \right\}_{n=1}^\infty }
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{ \stackrel{(#1)}{=} }
\newcommand{\leq}[1]{ \stackrel{(#1)}{\le} }
$
**Background Context:**

This is something one of my professors posed as a bit of an open question during a lecture, since my class and I struggled a bit to justify it rigorously on the spot. I think I have an approach, but just wanted to make sure it passed muster. (Especially because it ticks me off a little that I couldn't do it myself off the cuff.)

---

**Definitions & The Problem:**

First, recall: we define $\ell^1$ as

$$\ell^1 := \setb{ \text{all sequences }\seq{x_n} \subseteq \Bbb F }{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| < \infty }$$

for a field $\Bbb F$, usually $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$. We may assume the latter here for simplicity if we ever need to. This (once the axioms are verified) make $\ell^1$ a vector space over the chosen field.

I wish to justify part of that claim. Specifically, closure under addition; that is,

$$\left( x := \seq{x_n} \in \ell^1 \right) \text{ and } \left( y := \seq{y_n} \in \ell^1 \right) \implies x+y := \seq{x_n + y_n} \in \ell^1$$

To show this, note we need to show the corresponding sum for $x+y$ is finite; since we are summing absolute values, it is sufficient to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n+y_n|$ is bounded above.

---

**My Approach:**

So, my approach:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n + y_n| &\eq1 \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n + y_n| \\
&\leq2 \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + | y_n|\\
&\eq3 \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + \sum_{n=1}^N | y_n|\\
&\eq4 \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N | y_n|\\
&\eq5 \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n | + \sum_{n=1}^\infty | y_n| \\
&\stackrel{(6)}{<} \infty
\end{align*}

Justifications for each step:

1. Definition of infinite sum (limit of partial sums).
2. Triangle inequality.
3. Split the now-finite sums into two, separate sums.
4. Since the corresponding sums for $x,y$ converge, we may apply the limit to each sum individually.
5. Here we just convert back into two infinite sums from the definition. Note that each sum is finite since $x,y \in \ell^1$.
6. Sum of finite numbers is itself finite. (If we assume the fields $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ as intended, this is further clarified by the fact that the infinite sums are sequences of partial sums, with value as the limit of the sequence, and these fields form complete metric spaces with respect to their usual metrics. Thus, they sum to values in $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, and in turn the sum of these values is in the field in question from the field axioms. Not sure how to justify the claim for incomplete fields, e.g. $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb A$, though.)

Does this pass muster, in terms of rigor?

---

**Some Final Thoughts & Rambling:**

For what it's worth: in class we were able to quickly get as far as the equality at $(3)$, but from there we all kinda got stuck. The professor referenced it as being something more fundamental than what some of us were suggesting, so perhaps we were overthinking things. In any case, perhaps my approach above is a more proper justification?

One thing that does bug me is that from $(3)$ he had already written a $\le$ sign for the next step, so on the board it looked more like this:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n + y_n| &= \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n + y_n| \\
&\le \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + | y_n|\\
&= \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + \sum_{n=1}^N | y_n|\\
&\le (\cdots?)
\end{align*}

Sadly I don't have the notes to clarify: it is possible that we simply started with finite sums? Like maybe instead what we had is

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n + y_n| &\le \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + | y_n|\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + \sum_{n=1}^N | y_n|\\
&\le (\cdots?)
\end{align*}

and then intended to take the limit $N \to \infty$ after? If it's the former, I'm not sure what the next step entailed. If it's the latter, I think the intention was something along the limits of what I suggested, say

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n + y_n| &\le \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + | y_n|\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N |x_n | + \sum_{n=1}^N | y_n|\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^M |x_n | + \sum_{n=1}^M | y_n| \quad \forall M \ge N
\end{align*}

which would follow since $|x_n|,|y_n| \ge 0$ from definition, and I guess for $M \to \infty$ in particular, though I feel that is a bit convoluted for what the professor would likely intend.

Of course, it's also possible he intended to just have $=$ instead, or intended to combine several steps into one, or I'm just missing it. Still, if you can enlighten me as to how one might continue from either stance (if they're at all salvageable), that would also be appreciated.

But I'm mostly looking to see whether my own approach is sufficiently rigorous. Thanks for any insights you can give!

Comment: I'm not sure but I think basically you are defining $z_n = |x_n| + |y_n|$, and then you use the fact that $M \geq \sum_n^{N} z_n \geq \sum_n^{N} |x_n + y_n|$ for all $N$, where $M$ is the addition of the infinite sums of $|x_n|$ and $|y_n|$. Since the inequalities hold for all $N$, it must hold in the limit as well. I don't think there is anything non-rigorous about this is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach is sufficiently rigorous. Regarding what you said about your professor's notes, I think the finite sum interpretation works. As you said, it will be something like this
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n+y_n| & \leq \sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|+|y_n| \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^N|x_n|+\sum_{n=1}^N|y_n| \\
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|+\sum_{n=1}^\infty |y_n|
\end{align*}
with the last inequality coming from the fact that the sequence of partial sums is an increasing sequence. Set $R = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|+\sum_{n=1}^\infty |y_n|<\infty$, then we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^N|x_n+y_n|\leq R$$
for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n+y_n| \leq R <\infty.$$